# How to order divs from 1 column to 3 differents columns in different order using bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

The objective is to re-order the divs of a column when changing the size of the screen in 2 or 3 different columns and, with a different order.(*[SEE THE IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7uNl.jpg) *)**With no big empty space between the divs besides the margins**.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 order-md-2 offset-md-7">**A**</div>
  <div class="col-md-7 order-md-1">**B**</div>
  <div class="order-md-5">**C**</div>
  <div class="col-md-5 order-md-4 offset-md-7">**D**</div>
  <div class="col-md-5 order-md-3 offset-md-5">**E**</div>
  <div class="order-md-6">**F**</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I could put the things in order but there's a space (height) between A and E that I cannot join. Is this the correct way or there is another way?

I suppose if you tell me the way I can figure it out the way to do the 3rd column on my own.

[Here in the image, the example; divs in 1 col need to have a different order and be in 3 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYXbw.jpg)

Comment: Have you looked at [bootstrap masonry documentation](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/layout/bootstrap-masonry/#:~:text=Bootstrap%20masonry%20is%20a%20grid,by%20reducing%20any%20unnecessary%20gaps.), [and mdbootstrap example](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/marta-szymanska/613183)?

Comment: this is not possible with Flex, you need to use Grid for it, and if you want to go with bootstrap then you need jQuery code to achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `jquery` to swap `div` content of column `B` and `C`

`order` class for `column` name `D` and `E`

Dont forget to reload the page when you resize to mobile screen in order to see the change on `mobile devices` because I am using `jquery` to live detect the `mobile screen`

Here is the link of jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/ng9Lhfa5/

If you look at the live jsfiddle demo and  you resize your screen upto mobile just press `shift+enter` so you will get to know the col has switch their position

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get the inner HTML (Column B and Column C in this case)
  var x = document.getElementById("movefrom1").innerHTML
  var y = document.getElementById("movefrom2").innerHTML


  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) { // Check the browser's width
    // Move the element to where you want (moveto id)
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = y;
    // Replace the element by an empty string.
    document.getElementById("movefrom1").innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("movefrom2").innerHTML = ""
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<div class="container-fluid text-center text-white">
  <div class="row bg-primary">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 p-md-5" id="movefrom1">
      Column-B
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 order-0">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-12 p-5">Column A</div>
        <div class="col-12 p-md-0 p-5" id="b"></div>
        <div class="col-12 p-md-0 p-5" id="c"></div>
        <div class="col-12 p-5 order-md-4 order-5">Column E</div>
        <div class="col-12 p-5 order-md-5 order-4">Column D</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 bg-dark p-md-5" id="movefrom2">Column C</div>
        <div class="col-12 bg-secondary p-5">Column F</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```